# Get the specific frame from a video using FFMPEG (C#)

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg, frames

I would like to get every specified frames from a video using ffmpeg.
From now i have this code:

```
"-i example.mp4 -vf fps=30,select='between(t,2,3)' -vsync 0 image%d.bmp"
```

It generates the frames between the specifies secounds, but i would like to get frames by their number, for example: every 3, frame or every 10. frame.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
"-i example.mp4 -vf select='not(mod(n,5))' -vsync 0 image%d.bmp"
```

This will produce every 5th frame (0,5,10,15...)

(Removed fps filter .. that duplicates or drops frames from source).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Is there any way to speed it up a little bit ?

Comment: Not really. Most of the time is spent on the writeout. If you save selected frames to an AVI `-c:v bmp out.avi`, you may save ~25%.